# Laravel 5 in Fedora22 -> 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5, fedora

I changed of OS (debian8 to fedora22), but I get a problem in this OS. Laravel not working. I try muchas "solution" but not working.

my httpd.conf is:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

.httaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The permission are:

```
chmod 777 web-system
```

and I try with:

```
chown -R apache:apache web-system
```

but not working... firebug display this error:

[image]

Comment: View the error log in storage/logs to figure out the problem

Comment: SeLinux was blocking all attempts to write over files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:
SeLinux was blocking all attempts to write over files. I disabled it and go.
Although you can also create policies for SeLinux, as I read.

```
sudo nano /etc/selinux/config
```

changed `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=disabled` and reboot